# What is the best way to present an MBA+Developer profile?

Tags: job-search

I've just completed an MBA - I really enjoyed it, and it really opened my eyes to a lot of "business" things that, as an IT contract worker,  I never thought about before. Not just strategy stuff, but seeing how business people think differently from tech people.

Anyway, I'm looking at working in a development role for now, and I've been getting a lot of pushback having done the MBA. It seems engineers are sceptical of my desire to write code.

There is some merit to this, of course - I enjoy code, but I also really loved thinking strategically.

Regardless, what would be a strong response to why I did an MBA that helps me convince the questioner that I would be a good fit for a tech role?

Comment: Are these contract or permanent roles you're looking at? I'd have no problem hiring you on a (relatively) short term contract, but I'd have a lot of questions about your long term motivations before hiring you for a permanent role.

Comment: @PhilipKendall they're actually contract roles ~ I'm not sure if there was really a difference in response, so I'd be keen on thoughts for either perm or contract

Comment: so, why did you get the MBA? some context would help us figure out how to best spin it :)

Comment: Dev + MBA usually says to me Product Manager or Technical Product Manager. What was your concentration in your MBA? I got my MS in CS in the last two years and went into a business role. My current employer did question why I made the switch, but I had a good story around it.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this depends a lot on whether you're applying for a contract role or a permanent role.

For a contract role, I'm not that bothered about what your long term goals and motivations are. If you can do the relatively short term job I need you to do, then welcome along.

For a permanent role, I'd have concerns. Doing an MBA says to me "I want to be a strategic leader" - I'm going to need a lot of convincing that you're not going to be leaving in a year or two for some kind of strategic leadership role. If you can convince me that you actually want to stay in a technical role, then maybe - but it's going to be a hard sell. *Most* people don't drop the kind of money you need to drop to get an MBA without intending to recoup that investment.

Comment: OP doesn't state his location, but in many countries an MBA (or any other Master's degree) is almost free. But with freeness comes the difficulty of getting in. So there's a big merit in just being chosen for the programme.

Answer (score 2):

Explaining *why* you chose to pursue an MBA in the first place is a good start.

If it was to gain a better understanding of an organization as a whole but you still want to program, then great! Explain how you wanted to understand how your role as a developer plays into the bigger goal of the company and give examples of how your MBA will benefit you in a developer role and in the IT department (showing your understanding of the Silo Effect and its impact on a company might be a great option here). If you do not plan to move towards management and stay on the development side, emphasize that.

If you want to continue to program for the time being but plan to move to the management side then elaborate on how you want to continue to code and build a relationship with the company and IT department but see yourself moving into a new role in X months/years.

Understanding your motives for the MBA and what you want to do in the future (not just developing right now) is the best course of action. That way you don't get stuck in a position where you can't move into a management role if that's what you want or you aren't put in a role where they expect you to move into management but you don't want to.

Congrats on your MBA!